# Find heaviest users by CPU usage in AIX

Tags: monitoring, logging, aix, cpu-usage

Is there a way to find the top users according to CPU usage in AIX?  I would like to get history if possible, but I am open to installing some extra logging facilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with AIX but take a look at this link. Someone asks the same question and received a few answers.

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1238575&page=1

Comment: The shell script mentioned (http://the-welters.com/professional/scripts/hogs.txt) will do as I need for now.  NMON does not go into the detail by user that I need.  The other solutions seem to have the same limitations. I may look into expanding on the script.  I already added a little to remove the processes owned by root. Thanks, Romeo!